# Location not updating while walking, when app is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, appdelegate

I have one functionality in which when app is killed or terminated, I should get latitude and longitude of location.

When I'm riding my vehicle, I am getting latitude and longitude when app is killed/terminated.

But when I start to walk for few minutes then I am not getting latitude and longitude in app killed/terminated.

Below is my logic.

```
+ (CLLocationManager *)sharedLocationManager {
static CLLocationManager *_locationManager;

@synchronized(self) {
    if (_locationManager == nil) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
        _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
        _locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOther;
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    }
}
      return _locationManager; 
}

 - (id)init {
    if (self==[super init]) {
    //Get the share model and also initialize myLocationArray
    self.shareModel = [LocationShareModel sharedModel];
    self.shareModel.myLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}
    return self;
}

-(void)applicationEnterBackground{
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

//Use the BackgroundTaskManager to manage all the background Task
self.shareModel.bgTask = [BackgroundTaskManager sharedBackgroundTaskManager];
[self.shareModel.bgTask beginNewBackgroundTask];
}
```

Above is my Locationmanager class which I am calling from appdelegate

And in AppDelegate.m file, I have written like below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 UIAlertView * alert;

//We have to make sure that the Background App Refresh is enable for the Location updates to work in the background.
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied){

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                      message:@"The app doesn't work without the Background App Refresh enabled. To turn it on, go to Settings > General > Background App Refresh"
                                     delegate:nil
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted){

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                      message:@"The functions of this app are limited because the Background App Refresh is disable."
                                     delegate:nil
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

} else{
    self.locationTracker = [[LocationTracker alloc]init];
    [self.locationTracker startLocationTracking];

        //Send the best location to server every 60 seconds
        //You may adjust the time interval depends on the need of your app.
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {

        NSTimeInterval time = 10;
        self.locationUpdateTimer =
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateLocation)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
    }


}

return YES;
}
```

Any Tips ?? Thanks...

Comment: did you do related changes in Background Modes?

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder : Yes, I have enabled background modes for location and background fetch

Comment: Is internet or 3G required for location updating while walking ? @ReshmiMajumder

Comment: yes you need 3G

Comment: I have 3G...but still not working while walking.. @ReshmiMajumder

Comment: you can not get latitude and longitude of location when app is killed.

Comment: @balkaransingh : who told you Man ??? I am getting while I'm driving my vehicle. Read document in Apple. You are late !!

Comment: can you provide me the apple link where you read this ?

Comment: @balkaransingh: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html. read "Tracking the User’s Location" part

Comment: you don't need to use  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil]; for background location tracking

Comment: Hi! Did you solve your problem? If it possible I want to ask some questions about location sharing on iOS. Please contact me just.lyonya@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for "SignificantLocationChanges."  My research and experience with the API and the associated region monitoring is that since its using cell towers instead of GPS the resolution is VERY coarse.  We tried using it at 30 meters and it was erratic.  We bumped it to 100 meters and it was better.  It seems most people suggest 200 meters for region monitoring,  Its not surprising then that walking is not likely to trigger a "SignificantLocationChange" for some time, as 200 meters is a long ways to walk in a few minutes.

Comment: But there are other apps like "Zenly" which are updating location constantly even you walk normally

Comment: dont use significant location; use GPS.  Per apple: "The significant-change location service delivers updates only when there has been a significant change in the device’s location, such as 500 meters or more." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: There is a full tutorial and source code here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started